# Numpy: Generate 2 sequences of n random numbers with no overlaps

Tags: python, numpy, random

For `n = 5`, two random sequences of integers in [0, 2] might look like:

```
 l1 = [2, 0, 2, 2, 0]
 l2 = [0, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

I want to make sure that `l1[i] != l2[i]` for all `i`. My current method (looping over all values and replacing overlaps) seems clunky:

```
n = 5
sample = np.arange(3)
l1 = np.random.choice(sample, size=n)
l2 = np.random.choice(sample, size=n)
mask = np.ones(sample.size, dtype=bool)
for i in xrange(n):
    if l1[i] == l2[i]:
        mask[l1[i]] = False
        l2[i] = np.random.choice(sample[mask])
        mask[l1[i]] = True
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to calculate `l1` as you're doing, but then calculate a set of distances or offsets for each element, and make sure the offsets can't be 0:

```
ofs = l2 = np.random.choice(sample[:-1], size=n)+1
```

Then you can add these offsets to `l1` and wrap the results back into range:

```
l2 = (l1 + ofs) % (sample[-1] + 1)
```